# How open and display in new window pdf file in electron react app

Tags: reactjs, electron

I need display pdf file in my programm and it is desirable to display it in a new window electron.
I've added support for plugins in electron settings

```
    win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1080,
    height: 960,
    minWidth: 1080,
    minHeight: 960,
    show: false,
    icon: "",
    webPreferences: {
        plugins:true,
        webSecurity:false,
        nodeIntegration: true,
        webviewTag:true,
    }
});
```

And add tag in render `<webview style={{width:'500px', height:'500px'}} src="file://E:/programming/Tester-students/public/assets/doc/док.pdf" plugins="true"></webview>`
after that the file tries to **download** in the program.

Comment: I think it has to do with the version electron. I have 7.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using React with this packages:

**[React pdf viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-viewer-reactjs) and
[React new window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-new-window)**